# I'm trying to set up a table in mysql, but keep getting an error and can't figure out the correct way to fix it

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying create a table in mysql. I keep getting an error and I can't figure out why/how to fix it correctly.

My code so far is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scores(
date_played DATE,
member_score SCORE int(3)
);
```

And, my error is:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SCORE int(3)
    )' at line 3

I got this code to work, but its not quite what I need:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scores(
->     date_played DATE,
->     member_score varchar(25));
```

Instead of "varchar(25)", I need it to say "SCORE" and have it editable later on so I can input data.

How would I go about this??

I know this is a basic question, so thank you in advance!

Comment: The `INT` column type in MySQL is a fixed width 4 byte column.  So just use `member_score SCORE INT`

Comment: What is `SCORE` supposed to represent? A default value?

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear.  `SCORE` doesn't make sense.  I assume you intend:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scores (
    date_played DATE,
    member_score int(3)
);
```

If you want both a `score` column and a `member_score` column, you need to declare both:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scores (
    date_played DATE,
    score int(3),
    member_score int(3)
);
```

I also don't see any reason for `int(3)`.  If you want a three digit integer, use `decimal(3, 0)` instead.